# OpenVPN en CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, vpn

Tengo un VPS con CentOS 7 y ya he instalado openvpn y easy-rsa como sugieren la mayoría de los sitios que he visto, mi objetivo es crear una VPN del tipo site-to-site, mi acceso al VPS es a través de una consola SSH (la que trae PhpStorm), hasta ahora lo que he hecho....

```
yum install openvpn easy-rsa
```

Ambos paquetes se instalaron sin problemas, luego he creado el directorio de claves y he tratado decopiar el contenido del directorio original de easy-rsa a el de openvpn.

```
mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys 

cp -rf /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/3.0/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

hasta aquí no tuve problemas (que yo supiera), luego se supone que debo configurar las variables del certificado CA y ahí empieza la cosa, en los sitios que he consultado mencionan editar el contenido de "/vars"

```
nano  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars
```

pero esto me presenta un documento vacío y donde he consultado se supone que ya debería tener valores, aun así intento ponerle dichos valores, pero obviamente faltan cosas .. muchas imagino.

```
export KEY_SIZE=2048
export KEY_COUNTRY="AR"
export KEY_PROVINCE="PT" 
export KEY_CITY="BUENOS AIRES"
export KEY_ORG="PUNTOCOM" 
export KEY_EMAIL="soporte@redpunto.com" 
export KEY_CN=servidor.redpunto.com
export KEY_NAME=servidor
export KEY_OU=Sistemas
```

Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal ... o como puedo poner los archivos correctos en la ruta sugerida de:

```
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
```

O alguna otra idea para crear los certificados y archivos necesarios para que funcione la VPN.

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es desinstalar openvpn y easy-rsa y volver a instalar tratando de borrar todo regristro de estos

```
yum remove openvpn* easy-rsa*
```

y volviendo a instalar

al momento de instalar copia los directorios

```
cp /usr/share/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-1.0.0.cnf /etc/openvpn/
cp /usr/share/easy-rsa/2.0/whichopensslcnf /etc/openvpn/
cp /usr/share/easy-rsa/2.0/pkitool /etc/openvpn/
cp /usr/share/easy-rsa/2.0/vars /etc/openvpn
```

ya puedes seguir con la instalación como te dice el tutorial